# Switched to MahApps.Metro in .NET WPF and now it wont load Java jar process

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, jar, process

I am working on a Twitch Bot and the GUI is in .NET WPF and the bot is in Java. I open the bot and redirect all of the bot console output to a textbox called console. Everything worked perfectly as intended, but when I switched to MahApps.Metro to make the GUI look better, it instantly broke. I got it to run by moving a Timer initialization to the window onload function. Everything works now except it doesn't open the Java jar like it used to. I cannot figure this out for the life of me. Here is the code:

```
public void openBot()
    {
        try
        {
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "javaw";
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-jar bin\\bot.jar";
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            proc.OutputDataReceived += proc_OutputDataReceived;
            proc.Start();
            proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
        } catch (Exception E)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(E.ToString());
        }
    }

    void proc_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            console.Text = console.Text + "\n" + e.Data;
            console.ScrollToEnd();
        }));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the release version of the .exe instead of the debug version for whatever reason. FIXED